# Rails 3 generate migration - no up or down method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Just learning rails, am on to migrations and it all started off pretty logically until I hit something odd going on in the code;

```
rails generate migration AddRegionToSupplier
```

The above produces a migration file with only a "def change" method in it.

I googled this and found that this is exactly what is supposed to happen;

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

I would have expected it to generate a "def up" and "def down" method, so that the migration could be rolled back. Have I done something wrong in the generation or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: you tl;dr'ed XD don't worry happens a lot to me too lol

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [link you pasted](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html):

> Rails 3.1 makes migrations smarter by providing a new `change` method.
>   This method is preferred for writing constructive migrations (adding
>   columns or tables). **The migration knows how to migrate your database
>   and reverse it when the migration is rolled back without the need to
>   write a separate down method.**

So it looks like you don't have to worry about having a `def self.down` as Rails is now smart enough to know how to roll it back.

Comment: I like this answer. Simple and concise. :) How does Rails know how to reverse a migration if it doesn't have a down method to handle it? Is there some additional data being saved somewhere to keep track of this data?